# How to exclude certain time-frames from a SignalFx Detector?

Tags: signalfx

We have a service that gets very little calls/traffic at night time, and as a result even a few errors trip up the SignalFx Detector.
Is there a way we can exclude certain time frames? For example - do not alert in the middle of the night. Alert from 6am-11pm